# Controller behaviour with ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to get a hold on sending data to MySql via ajax and have been watching online tutorials. In the examples, the controller method always seems to end with an echo statement which is returned to the js script. Under other circumstances, if I put an echo statement in a controller method it would be output to the view so why does this not happen after an ajax request?

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajax works with js, and the response by ajax request can only be handle through js. 
Reason => after generating ajax response on server, it bounce back to client/browser, where server side language doesn't work, so you need to manage your code/logic through client side language JS in your ajax success block.

```
$.ajax({                    
  url: 'content/get.php',     
  type: 'post', // performing a POST request
  data : {
    data1 : 'value' // will be accessible in $_POST['data1']
  },
  dataType: 'json',                   
  success: function(data)         
  {
    // success block
  } 
});
```